I cannot find the Example Folder in the vscode-icons repository
I need the all the file in the Example Folder in this Repository https://github.com/vscode-icons/vscode-icons?tab=readme-ov-file
But I cannot find them. Does anyone have that folder?
I need the Example folder in this Repository. Please help me!
It large number of file that I have to create manually
